# After deleting and recreating a cloudformation stack, I get an error message api key already existing when it doesn't

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless, aws-api-gateway

### Scenario

My pipeline deploys a cloudformation stack to an AWS account.
My pipeline removes the cloudformation stack from the account.
My pipeline tries to deploy the cloudformation stack again but get the following error.

`Resource handler returned message: "ApiKey with name service-automation-test-feature-deploy already exists" (RequestToken: c19e0817-79a1-2257-fe79-2ca2901325ff, HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists)`

### Examination

There exists no api key with that name.
Even if I change the stage name (used to determine key name), I get an error that the key already exists for a key that never ever existed with that name.

### Further detail

This uses the serverless format where the usage plan is specified with each of it's api keys.

### Speculation

Something is not being cleaned with the stack deletion, which is prevents the same stack from being redeployed.  But it doesn't seem to be the api key.

### Question

What is causing this error to trigger?

Comment: Did you try with new api key value, so that you don't reuse old one?

Comment: Value should not be set and generated randomly.

Comment: Though it is interesting that api keys are actually unique by value and not name, not sure I actually have the option to test this.